# How can I link to a lightbox image on a different page

Tags: html, linker, lightbox

Website that I'm working on: http://www.cvolden.net

On the top navigation menu, there is a "Products" dropdown that displays products. When the user clicks on one of these options, I want them to be taken to the products page and have the lightbox for that specific item expanded.

Because I don't know how to properly link to the items on the products page, clicking on the dropdown items simply takes the user to the products page, but does not open up the specific lightbox items.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks.